# Block IPv6 addresses in my .htaccess file but I get 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, ipv6, 500-error, ip-blocking

I want to block all IP Addresses starting like this `2a01:598:xxx` in my `.htaccess` file on my WordPress website.

But everytime I edit my `.htaccess` file I can't visit my website anymore. I get an Internal Server Error.

And the end of my `.htaccess` file after `# END WordPress` I added the Code:

```
Require all granted
Require not ip 2a01:598:
```

I also tried this variation:

```
Require all granted
Require not ip 2a01:598:::
```

But nothing worked. Even when I try to block my own IPv4 Address like this:

```
Require all granted
Require not ip 11.222.33.444 (with my IP instead)
```

I get a 500 Internal Server Error?

I don't know what to do. I just want to block all IP-Addresses starting like this `2a01:598:` in my `.htaccess` file.

Comment: FWIW, if you can drop traffic at the firewall, its better.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a 500 Internal Server Error you need to check your server's error log for details of the error. The 500 status is simply a catch-all response returned to the client because of some specific server error.

There are a number issues here that result in errors...

> ```
> Require not ip 2a01:598:
> :
> Require not ip 2a01:598:::
> ```

In both these cases, the specified IPv6 addresses `2a01:598:` and `2a01:598:::` are not valid - hence the 500 error response. You could use `2a01:598::` (2 colons), but that is short for the *specific* IPv6 address `2a01:598:0:0:0:0:0:0`, which is not what you require.

With IPv4 addresses, Apache allows you to use partial IP addresses (whole octets), eg. `203.0.113` (no trailing dot). For IPv6 addresses, you might expect `2a01:598` to be permitted, however, this does not appear to be supported as this again results a 500 response and the "The specified IP address is invalid" error being logged.

To specify an IPv6 address range you need to use CIDR notation. For example, to specify the range of IPs that "start `2a01:598:`", you would need to use `2a01:598::/32` using CIDR notation ([example](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv6CIDRToRangeResult?ipAddress=2a01%3A598%3A%3A%2F32)).

> ```
> Require all granted
> Require not ip 11.222.33.444
> ```

When you specify multiple `Require` directives in this way, Apache *defaults* to a `<RequireAny>` container. *Negated* directives (ie. `Require not`) are not permitted in a `<RequireAny>` container; hence the 500 error. ("negative Require directive has no effect in `<RequireAny>` directive" being logged as the error.) You need to explicitly use the `<RequireAll>` container here.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require

### Solution

So, you would need to do something like the following instead:

```
<RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require not ip 2a01:598::/32
</RequireAll>
```

> And the end of my `.htaccess` file after `# END WordPress`

Logically, this should go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker. Blocking directives should be first. However, it probably doesn't matter (because of the way Apache processes different modules).

Comment: Hi,

Okay I got it running now and the ip adress blocking is working with the ipv4 adress.

But even when i  add this code to my htaccess he can still visit my website. 

I also tried it with my own IPv6 adress. I still can access my website. If i block my IPv6 adress like this?

`<RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require not ip 2a01:598::/32
</RequireAll>`

I tried the Code with my IP Adress. It is not working?

Comment: Maybe a typo? Or maybe /32 is not correct in your case? Can you give more details on the address or even an example? (you can obfuscate by replacing some numbers with "x", but please don't remove any zeros).

Comment: what details you need to know excatly from the adress?